# Changing string representation of choices in a Symfony 2.6 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.6

I'm using building a form type that uses a form field subscriber to render some of the form fields.

The subscriber returns form options for a given field. One of the options is "choices":

```
    $formOptions = [
        ...
        'choices' => $choices,
    ];
```

`$choices` are entities.
Consequently, they will be rendered in a  form by means of `__toString()` of the objects.

The `__toString()` method would look something like:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

However, I want the "choices" representation to be `$name . $id` (name concatenated with the object ID).
At the same time, I do not want to modify the object's `__toString()` method since I want a different string representation only in this one form field, and not all over the system.

What options do I have?
Do I have any granular control on how Symofny form fields display passed choices?

Comment: Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: Choices could be populated by a function in the entity's repository.

Comment: I've now specified in the post title that I'm looking for a solution in Symofny 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property option according to [entity field documentation 2.6](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

```
$builder->add('users', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeHelloBundle:User',
    'property' => 'customToString',
));
```

Just make sure that the property name matches the method name

```
    /**
     * @return string 
     * Here you print the attributes you need
     */
    public function customToString()
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%s,
            $this->$name . $this->$id,


        );
    }
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Nice and easy. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since Symfony 2.7 you can use the `choice_label` option with a callback to dynamically create the labels of your choices:

```
$builder->add('name', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => ...,
    'choice_label' => function ($choice) {
        return $choice->name.$choice->id;
    },
));
```

This example assumes that your choices are objects that have public `$id` and `$name` properties.

Comment: Omg, I'm working on Symofny 2.6.9. Sorry to have misinformed you. However, for 2.7 you're answer is what would surely solve the problem.

Comment: Super great. This should be the accepted answer because in the accepted one, the form makes you modify the Entity, which is non sense

Answer (score 2):

*You can try with something like this ? :*

```
$formChoices = [];
foreach ($choices as $key => $entity) {
   $formChoices[$entity->getId()] = sprintf('%s %s', $entity->getName(), $entity->getId());
}

$formOptions = [
        ...
        'choices' => $formChoices,
    ];
```

Comment: Yes, I'm coming to a conclusion that I will have to resort to this. Another method might be the "choice_list" option http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-list